# Multiple activites for a layout in an login app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hey iam new to coding/java/android , please go easy on me

I have added if else statement to login button ,

```
if(username = admin && password = admin){ 
then go to admin activity 
}else if(username = manager && password = manager){
then go to manager activity 
}else if(username = user && password = user){
then go to user activity
}else{
display text wrong password
}
```

when in admin activity it calls for button add_user
, in manager activity it calls for button order_items
and in user activity it calls for button sales_report

all the buttons are defined in activity_users_area.xml

**Issue/Problem**

Issue is when i login as admin in app it will show all the buttons displayed in layout file activity_users_area.xml
same goes if i login as manager or user

I want it to display only whats called in the respective Java class , how can i achieve this

Iam using same layout for Admin Manager and User because , In future i might add buttons which will be common for Admin User and Manager or Admin and Manger etc ...

please don't suggest me to create database for admin , user and manager 
looking for an option to solve without them

This what my layout  looks like **activity_users_area.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".AdminAreaActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add User"
        android:id="@+id/bAddUser"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remove User"
        android:id="@+id/bRemoveUser"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bAddUser"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Stock"
        android:id="@+id/bChangeStock"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bRemoveUser"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sales Report"
        android:id="@+id/bSalesReport"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bChangeStock"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Customer"
        android:id="@+id/bChangeCustomer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bChangeStock"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Collection Report"
        android:id="@+id/bCollectionReport"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bSalesReport"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stock Report"
        android:id="@+id/bStockReport"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bCollectionReport"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pay Collect"
        android:id="@+id/bPayCollect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bStockReport"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item Sales"
        android:id="@+id/bItemSales"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bPayCollect"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loan Collect"
        android:id="@+id/bLoanCollect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bItemSales"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Order Items"
        android:id="@+id/bOrderItems"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bLoanCollect"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my **LoginActivity.java**

```
package online.klok.mobpos;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

        registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);


            }
        });

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
                EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

                if (username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
                    Intent adminIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminAreaActivity.class);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(adminIntent);
                } else if(username.getText().toString().equals("manager") && password.getText().toString().equals("manager")) {
                    Intent managerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ManagerAreaActivity.class);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(managerIntent);
                }else if(username.getText().toString().equals("user") && password.getText().toString().equals("user")) {
                    Intent userIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(userIntent);
                }else {
                    //wrong password
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my **AdminAreaActivity.java**

```
package online.klok.mobpos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class AdminAreaActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

        Button bAddUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddUser);
      bAddUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

          }
      });
  }
}
```

Here is my **ManagerAreaActivity.java**

```
package online.klok.mobpos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by klok on 1/7/16.
 */
public class ManagerAreaActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);


        final Button bOrderItems = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOrderItems);
        bOrderItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my **UserAreaActivity.java**

```
package online.klok.mobpos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by klok on 1/7/16.
 */
public class UserAreaActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

        final Button bSalesReport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSalesReport);
        bSalesReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid pasting large block of code, make it concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to change your buttons visibility :

```
    if(adminActivity){
        buttonYouDontWant.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

GONE means that the button will not be visible and won't take up space on your layout.
Use

```
    View.VISIBLE
```

to set it back to visible.

With that said, you may want to create a custom view programmatically, which would help you to handle the common parts of AdminManager and User easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think button visibility will work. You can make all the views invisible first and then in respect layouts you can make them visible as you want to.
Use View.VISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_users_area.xml,add this line to all button

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

in AdminAreaActivity.java, add these lines in onCreate() Method.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);
final Button badduser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddUser);
badduser.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

Now only add_user button will shown in your AdminAreaActivity.
likewise, add above 3 lines to all other activities.